# Google sheets API - get sheet details

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api

I have looking through the Google Sheets Api documentation to see if I can find how to access a sheet's information (like creation data, last update date, etc) but I can't seem to find anything.

Does anyone know if this is possible and can redirect me to some more documentation?

Thanks

-----EDIT-----

As suggested, I can probably find some information using the google drive api. But this will only give me information about the file, not the individual sheets inside of it, right? Any way to get that level of detail (sheet A was modified at date X, while sheet B was modified at date Y).

Comment: This thread seems to be similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43411138/get-google-sheets-last-edit-date-using-sheets-api-v4-java

Comment: In the current stage, unfortunately, information like `sheet A was modified at date X, while sheet B was modified at date Y` cannot be retrieved using Sheets API and Drive API. I think that this is the current answer to your question. I apologize for this. So how about reporting it for the future request of the Google issue tracker? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)